# Increasing batch size decreases trainable parameters

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am using a LSTM+attention layer for sentence classification task. I have observed that in simple LSTM model, my total trainable parameters were 14705 with batch size of 64, but when I am using attention layer with  LSTM, for the same batch size, the trainable parameters decreases to 230. While for batch size of 4, it increases to 3077. Also, since batch size is 64 in attention layer, it is increasing by 1 only in epochs.

How is it possible?

This is the screenshot for attention layer for batch size 64

[image]

And this is the screenshot for LSTM layer for batch size 64.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the number of data, not parameters.

Bigger batch leads to smaller number of batches naturally.

100 sentences = 1 batchsize * 100 batches = 10 batchsize * 10 batches

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. For my Bi-LSTM model, for batch size=64, there are 14705 sentences in training and for the same batch size with attention layer, the number of sentences is just 230. How is that possible?